# Delete everything between two surrounding characters

Tags: neovim, movement, ideavim

Commands I use a lot are commands like:

`dib` (delete everything between two surrounding parantheses)

`di{` (delete everything between two surrounding curly brackets)

... it works for a few other characters as well.

How do I make it work for arbritrary charcters?

For instance, I would like the following:

`di`  (delete everything between two surrounding spaces)

`dit` (delete everything between two surrounding 't' characters)

... and so on; it should work for every character.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but `di ` would be the same as `diW` ('delete inside WORD = contiuous text delimited by whitespace. Aslo, `dit` already means 'delete inside tag', so you'd be losing a text object by doing it.

Comment: If you don't mind a plugin, [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) almost does what you want. Instead of `di{char}`, `dis{char}` deletes everything between two {char}s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a few functions to do 'delete', 'change', and 'yank' in between, and
'around' two characters on a line, which are called using normal mode commands:

```
function! DeleteInside(char)
    execute "normal! F".a:char
    execute "normal! ldt".a:char
endfunction
function! DeleteAround(char)
    execute "normal! F".a:char
    execute "normal! df".a:char
endfunction

function! ChangeInside(char)
    :call DeleteInside(a:char)
    :startinsert
endfunction
function! ChangeAround(char)
    :call DeleteAround(a:char)
    :startinsert
endfunction

function! YankInside(char)
    :call DeleteInside(a:char)
    execute "normal! u"
endfunction
function! YankAround(char)
    :call DeleteAround(a:char)
    execute "normal! u"
endfunction

nnoremap <LEADER>di :call DeleteInside('')<left><left>
nnoremap <LEADER>ci :call ChangeInside('')<left><left>
nnoremap <LEADER>yi :call YankInside('')<left><left>
nnoremap <LEADER>da :call DeleteAround('')<left><left>
nnoremap <LEADER>ca :call ChangeAround('')<left><left>
nnoremap <LEADER>ya :call YankAround('')<left><left>
```

With the cursor in between the x's:

```
x delete me x
```

Use <LEADER>di to get:

```
:call DeleteInside('')
```

and you just need to put the desired letter between the quotes (the cursor will
already be in the right place) and hit enter to get:

```
xx
```

#### Update

If you can't use a function to do it, then the only thing I can think of is
'hard coding' the problem (you could use the same pattern for 'change' and
'yank', if desired):

```
nnoremap dia Faldta
nnoremap dib Fbldtb
nnoremap dic Fcldtc
nnoremap did Fdldtd
   .      .    .
   .      .    .
   .      .    .
```

N.B. I would not do this for ones that already exist (like `dib`)! You could
use di in the nnoremaps to avoid interfering with default mappings.
Also these will not be repeatable with the dot command.

#### Update 2:

See other (better?) solutions to [this (possible duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856240/can-you-substitute-or-delete-between-commas-or-any-arbitrary-character-in-vi-v). Also
[there is a plugin to do this in a nice way.](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim)

Comment: Great! Is it possible to have it not be a function? [Because function calls doesn't seem to be working in jetbrains](https://i.gyazo.com/7f1fe362ac1e6a2e9d825f440b8bf439.mp4).

Comment: @SebastianNielsen I'm not sure how to do that (if I figure it out I'll edit the answer). I did notice a mistake in the function (the `."\<CR>"` is not needed and causes problems). But I guess that still doesn't work in jetbrains..